# How to repeat a few characters a few times in bash?

Tags: bash, design-patterns, repeat

In a bash script, I have to include the same file several times in a row as an argument. Like this:

```
convert image.png image.png image.png [...] many_images.png
```

where `image.png` should be repeated a few times.

Is there a bash shorthand for repeating a pattern?

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/86340/linux-command-to-repeat-a-string-n-times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works with a given integer (10 in the example below).

```
$ echo $(yes image.png | head -n10)
image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png
```

It can also be used with `xargs`:

```
$ yes image.png | head -n10 | xargs echo
image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png image.png
```

Answer (score 10):

You can do this using brace expansion:

```
convert image.png{,,} many_images.png
```

will produce:

```
convert image.png image.png image.png many_images.png
```

Brace expansion will repeat the string(s) before (and after) the braces for each comma-separated string within the braces producing a string consiting of the prefix, the comma-separated string and the suffix; and separating the generated strings by a space.

In this case the comma-separated string between the braces and the suffix are empty strings which will produce the string image.png three times.

Comment: This is the best solution for a fixed, small number of repetitions, but doesn't work well for a large or flexible number of repetitions.

Comment: This is neat. I like this. But as Philipp mentioned, I kind of have to prefer a parametrized solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash

function repeat {
    for ((i=0;i<$2;++i)); do echo -n $1 " "; done
}

convert $(repeat image.png 3) many_images.png
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that uses arrays and is thus robust for strings containing spaces, newlines etc.

```
declare -a images
declare -i count=5
for ((i=0; i<count; ++i))
do
    images+=(image.png)
done
convert "${images[@]}" many_images.png
```

Comment: You can get by without the `declare` statements. In your example, Bash will do the right thing for you. You would just set your count like this: `count=5`. The array will be created by virtue of the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
convert $(printf "image.png %.s" {1..5}) many_images.png
```

This will repeat `image.png` 5 times before `many_images.png`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid slow code that opens unnecessary instances of bash using $(command) or `command` you can use brace expansion.

To repeat a filename 3 times do:

```
file="image.png"; convert "${file[0]"{1..3}"}" many_images.png
```

or a more controversial version that uses a variable to specify number of repeated file names:

```
n=10; file="image.png"; eval convert \"\${file[0]\"{1..$n}\"}\" many_images.png
```

How it works.

${file[0]} is same as $file or ${file}

Bash does brace expansion first and so it makes up a sequence like this:

```
${file[0]1} ${file[0]2} ${file[0]3}
```

Bash kindly ignore these extra numbers so you get

```
${file[0]} ${file[0]} ${file[0]}
```

Which simplifies to

```
${file} ${file} ${file}
```

and then

```
$file $file $file
```

Which is what we want.

Answer (score 0):

Shortest [POSIX 7](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html) solution I have found so far:

```
N=3
S="image.png "
printf "%${N}s" | sed "s/ /$S/g"
```

since `yes`, `seq` and `{1..3}` are not POSIX.

For your specific example:

```
N=
convert $(printf "%${N}s" | sed "s/ /image.png /g") many_images.png
```