# use for loop to add 3 asterix before and after each word

Tags: linux, bash

I have an issue where I cannot complete this script. Here is part of the script that works. This is a linux bash script as well.

```
echo -n "Please enter file "
read file
if [ -f $file ]
then
        echo "$file found."
else
        echo "$file not found."
fi
```

Write a script using the “for” loop that prints every word of a file with 3 asterix (*) before and after each word. The script should prompt the user to enter a file name and there must be validation of the existence of the file and whether the file is a regular text file.
**Hint:** use the cat, read, and file commands as well as an if statement in conjunction with your `for` loop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to repeat a few characters a few times in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423791/how-to-repeat-a-few-characters-a-few-times-in-bash)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this script:

```
echo -n "Please enter file "
read file
if [ -f $file ]
then
        echo "$file found."
        if [[ $(file -b $file) == 'ASCII text' ]]
         then
         for word in $(cat $file)
          do echo "***$word***"
         done
        else
         echo "$file is not a regular text file"
        fi
else
        echo "$file not found."
fi
```

with this input file:

```
word1 word2
word3
```

this script give:

```
Please enter file test.inp
test.inp found.
***word1***
***word2***
***word3***
```